# Eclipse, prevent panel icons to auto hide

Tags: eclipse

The Icons of all of Panels in my Eclipse are hidden till I hover my mouse on them.

[image: Panel with hidden Icons]

I have searched many hours in Google and Eclipse to find out a Setting without a success. How can I set them to be shown permanently like this image?

[image: Desired behaviour]

Comment: mmm, Downvoting without a comment or solution ?! I'm not sure if it is really a professional behaviour :(

Comment: This question is perfectly valid IMHO. This is the Eclipse behavior when splitting an editor view by dragging one window to a corner of the editor Pane. so this just reflects the layout of your windows.

Comment: Thank you Torsten, is there any way to show icons normally? As I mentioned, ALL of my Panels are showing the same tiny hoverable icons which makes it difficult to work.

Comment: Never seen that, it may be useful if you state Java and Eclipse versions and operating system details.

Comment: it is actually a customized Eclipse ("Anypoint Studio"), Java version is 8 and all are running on Ubuntu 14.2

Comment: Try disabling GTK3: `export SWT_GTK3=0;./eclipse`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For other people who have the same Problem, This has solved my Problem.

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1465712